# AWS SQS ReceiveMessage receiving less / fewer messages than requested?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sqs

I have a simple SQS configured, and I want to process **4** messages at a time.
In my test, It has **2** "available" messages. When I get the message, it results in only **1** at a time. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Queue general configuration]

[image: sqs list]

```
sqs = boto3.client('sqs')
response = sqs.receive_message(
    QueueUrl=queue_url,
    MaxNumberOfMessages=4
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, the behaviour is expected.

That is due to the distributed nature of SQS (and most AWS services). Basically not all nodes have all messages available and the node you talk to may return any number between 0 and MaxNumberOfMessages if any are available. To actually receive multiple message in a single call you need to have 100s or 1000+s of messages in the queue and even then you can be unlucky and receive very few messages.

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html):

> If the number of messages in the queue is small (fewer than 1,000), you most likely get fewer messages than you requested per ReceiveMessage call. If the number of messages in the queue is extremely small, you might not receive any messages in a particular ReceiveMessage response. If this happens, repeat the request.

Comment: Thanks, @luk2302. I modified my code to get messages while `len(msgs) < 4` or the result of `receive_message` is empty.

Comment: @Lücks note that you could receive 0 message even if one is available - I do not know what your actual goal is but just want to point out that it might not be sufficient to only poll until receive_message is 0 once.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. It's a job that keeps running all the time, so the worst scenario I get on the next iteration.

Comment: @Lücks then of course you are perfectly fine. You should consider adding long-polling since a lot of the time you will receive no messages and requesting too often will actually cost quite some money.